# Security header error for ksoap2

Tags: android, wsdl, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am getting the following error while trying to connect to a .Net web service

> SoapFault - faultcode: 'q0:Security' faultstring: 'Security
>   requirements are not satisfied because the security header is not
>   present in the incoming message.'

Here is the code on server side that creates the security header

```
        public override XmlElement GetXml(XmlDocument document) {
        if (null == document) throw new ArgumentException("document");

        XmlElement root = document.CreateElement("abc", "TokenName", "http://testurl.com");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id)) {
            root.SetAttribute(WSUtility.Prefix, WSUtility.NamespaceURI);
            root.SetAttribute(WSUtility.AttributeNames.Id, WSUtility.NamespaceURI, Id);
        }

        XmlElement machineIdElement = document.CreateElement("abc", "machineId", "http://testurl.com");

        machineIdElement.InnerText = "060a5270-7ae7-11e2-b92a-0800200c9a66";

        root.AppendChild(machineIdElement);

        XmlElement inspectorIdElement = document.CreateElement("dac", "insId", "http://testurl.com");

        inspectorIdElement.InnerText = "dc0a5270-7ae7-11e2-b92a-0800200c9a66";

        root.AppendChild(inspectorIdElement);

        return root;
    }
```

Can some one tell me how I can create a security header for ksoap2 based on the above code.
Appreciate any help

Thanks in advance
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Try This.....

```
// create header
        Element[] header = new Element[1];
        header[0] = new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd","Security");
        header[0].setAttribute(null, "mustUnderstand","1");

        Element usernametoken = new Element().createElement("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "UsernameToken");
        usernametoken.setAttribute(null, "Id", "UsernameToken-1");
        header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT,usernametoken);

        Element username = new Element().createElement(null, "n0:Username");
        username.addChild(Node.IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE,"AJAY");
        usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT,username);

        Element pass = new Element().createElement(null,"n0:Password");
        pass.setAttribute(null, "Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
        pass.addChild(Node.TEXT, "hello");
        usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, pass);
```